# What are the parameters for TrigramAssocMeasure.chi_sq()?

Tags: python, nltk

I am working on sentiment analysis and I am using the nltk package. I am not getting which values to take for the parameter :

```
(n_iix, n_ixi, n_xii) = n_iix_tuple
```

it gives me the error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Comment: I corrected the title (fixing the function name) and tried to improve the question a bit.

Comment: What is the source of the `n_iix_tuple`?

Comment: What is your input? What is your output? Which function are you referring to (post a link to the code from https://github.com/nltk/nltk) ? Having those available would help us to answer your question =) Now it's a little unclear what you're asking.